# How to stop animation of a specific movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript

I've created an animation (right click on timeline and create animation) and given it an object name. If I call tank.stop(), the animation will stop successfully. However, if I call tank.body.stop(), it won't work.

There are 2 object names - the movieClip object name AND the name of the animation itself. I don't know how to stop animating a specific part, not all the parts. If I write tank.animObjectName.stop(), I get an error.

```
// If I stop animating the main movieclip then all the child will stop 
// animating also
main movieclip ->
{ 

  head //how to stop animating head?

  body //how to stop animating body?

  legs //how to stop animating legs?


}
```

Comment: I test a as3 no problem. you mean as2?

Comment: I mean adobe flash(cs5), click on the layer where the animation is created then look at the properties tab, there you will see the field where to put the animation name itself, the object name of that animation is a AnimationFactory type, I don't know how to stop the animation using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created from context menu animations are instances of AnimatorFactory class.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/AnimatorFactory.html

There is no ability to control them (start/stop).

You need use classic scheme of movieclip tree. Root - main movieclip with all content. Every animated part is a movieclip with animation inside root clip. Example:

```
tank (no animation, only child movieclips, 1 frame at all)
--body (movieclip with animation of body inside)
--weapon (movieclip with animation of gun inside)
--banner (movieclip with animation of banner inside)
```

To stop body, write tank.body.stop(); Body will paused, but weapon and banner will play. When you want to stop all parts, write command for all parts:

```
tank.body.stop();
tank.weapon.stop();
tank.banner.stop();
```

If you have some animations and want to convert them to movieclip:

1. Select frames of your amination with mouse. You can select frames in many layers simultaneously, use SHIFT key etc
2. In context menu select Cut frames
3. Create new movieclip in library
4. Select 1st frame, in context menu select Paste frames
5. Return to main movieclip, create layer if need
6. Drag movieclip from library (step 3) into frame, place in proper position

Maybe there are faster method, but i don't know them...

Comment: when you click on the timeline where the animation is created , in the properties tab you will see "give animation name", I tought  using that name I can stop the animation, but it gives me an error

Comment: Sorry, you can give animation instance name, and it will be instance of AnimatorFactory class. You can't start or stop them, you can change some properties and add new target to animation... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/AnimatorFactory.html

Comment: excuse me, can you exaplain a little detailer about replace the layer of body animation with movie clip, containing the animantion,

Comment: so tank is a container with no animantion, then the children(body, weapon, banner) are also containers that have a INSIDE an animated children, I understand you right?

Comment: Exactly! That method allows you to create many tanks (by as3 or by hands in Flash environment), give each tank individual instancename and control each part of each tank as you wish.